# How can I set the PATH for supervisord so it finds the executables

Tags: python, shell, environment-variables, supervisord

I'm trying to setup `supervisor.conf`. One of my apps requires node.js, but node is not installed system wise. Also, because it needs to bind to port 80 it need to run as root. How can I modify the `PATH` variable so that supervisord can find the `node` executable (which is located in a directory) and run the node.js app.

---

I'm trying to do it like this

```
[supervisord]
environment=PATH=/path/to/where/node/executable/is

[program:web]
command=node web.js -c config.json
```

This fails with

```
2011-08-25 16:49:29,494 INFO spawnerr: can't find command 'node'
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can just set the absolute path to the command:

```
[program:web]
command=/path/to/where/node/executable/is/node web.js -c config.json
```

Comment: -1 Does not answer the question, unfortunately. Why does setting PATH not work and/or how do you fix it?

Comment: The question was "how do I make this work", not "why doesn't it work". The answer solves the problem. If you have a better idea, post your own answer

Answer (score 12):

You can add it in the command using env:

```
[program:web]
command=env PATH="/path/to/where/node/executable/is" node web.js -c config.json
```

It seems environment does not work on some cases.

Comment: This couldn't be applied if you were using a bash script or something else that relays on current `$PATH`. In my case I needed to run sentry from within a virtualenv directory and it didn't work but after setting `command=env PATH="/path/to/virtualenv/bin:%(ENV_PATH)s" sentry start` it worked perfectly and the environment PATH is retained.

Comment: This works for me ! OS: Mac OSX 10.9, supervisor: 3.1.3.

Answer (score 5):

A pattern I've started using with supervisor (which is similar to zenbeni's) is to use a shell script to start whichever program I'm running which allows setup of environment variables etc.

e.g.

```
#!/bin/sh
export EXAMPLE_VARIABLE=something
export PYTHONPATH=/something
export PATH=$PATH:/somewhere/else
exec python somescript.py
```

The use of 'exec' is important. It replaces /bin/sh with the program being executed instead of spawning it as a child. This means that there aren't any additional processes around, and also signals work as expected.

The (small) advantage of this over zenbeni's method is that when updating environment variables etc it only takes a supervisor restart, i.e. no reread/update etc is required. This advantage gets bigger when using an event listener if you hit the same bug I did (full restart of supervisor to update event listener environment variables).